VSCodium network share access (Flatpak)
Is there a way to enable VSCodium to read/write smb or afp mounted folders mounted through Files app?
Reading various sources says adding xdg-run/gvfs to Filesystem > Other files using Flatseal should allow Other Locations to show network shares, but it does nothing.
Neither does adding org.gtk.vfs.* to Talks or /run/media to Other files.
VSCodium can only access local subfolders of Home, / or disks mounted under /media.
On Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS.
